# How to make bounce effect on amchart

Tags: jquery, css, amcharts

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/3d-stacked-column-chart/

I am created  3D SVG chart myself which given in the above link.But i am not able to get bounce effect as same as given in above link.can any one tell me how to get this bounce effect.

Comment: no one here who can help me...??

Comment: did you find the solution??

Answer (score 0):

Click the 'edit' button in the link that you have pasted in your question. There you have got the whole configuration responsible of displaying this particular chart.

The property responsible for animating the chart is `"startDuration": 1,`. It indicates that the animation should last 1 second. The effect of 'bouncing' is the default animation available for the type of chart you have linked to.